# Get time difference between multiple datestamps and sum total using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to know the approach i should take to calculate the time between each pair of timestamps as a total.

Example:

```
   4 '08/02/2018 11:14' 
   3 '08/02/2018 11:13' 
   2 '08/02/2018 11:13' 
   1 '08/02/2018 11:12'
```

This function should open a CSV file/input

Time elapsed in minutes between:
 1 and 2 = 1 minute,
 2 and 3 = 0 minute,
 3 and 4 = 1 minute, then i would need to sum all the results from the differences as total, and to be returned as string.

Please see idea from my CSV data

```
ROW NO  |   DATETIMESTAMP  |   Minutes
----------------------------------------    
  36.     '08/02/2018 11:14' +1 min
  35.     '08/02/2018 11:13' +0 min
  34.     '08/02/2018 11:13' +1 min
  33.     '08/02/2018 11:12' +0 min
  32.     '08/02/2018 11:12' +4 min
  31.     '08/02/2018 11:08' +0 min 
  30.     '08/02/2018 11:08' +1 min 
  29.     '08/02/2018 11:07' +0 min 
  28.     '08/02/2018 11:07' +1 min 
  27.     '08/02/2018 11:06' +1 min 
  26.     '08/02/2018 11:05' +2 min 
  25.     '08/02/2018 11:03' +2 min 
  24.     '08/02/2018 11:01' +2 min 
  23.     '08/02/2018 10:59' +2 min 
  22.     '08/02/2018 10:57' +2 min 
  21.     '08/02/2018 10:55' +1 min
  20.     '08/02/2018 10:54' +3 min 
  19.     '08/02/2018 10:51' +27 min
  18.     '08/02/2018 10:24' +4 min
  17.     '08/02/2018 10:20' +2 min
  16.     '08/02/2018 10:18' +8 min
  15.     '08/02/2018 10:10' +2 min
  14.     '08/02/2018 10:08' +2 min
  13.     '08/02/2018 10:06' +0 min
  12.     '08/02/2018 10:06' +2 min
  11.     '08/02/2018 10:04' +2 min
  10.     '08/02/2018 10:02' +0 min
  9.      '08/02/2018 10:02' +2 min 
  8.      '08/02/2018 10:00' +1 min
  7.      '08/02/2018 09:49' +10 min
  6.      '08/02/2018 09:39' +3 min
  5.      '08/02/2018 09:36' +1 min
  4.      '08/02/2018 09:35' +1 min
  3.      '08/02/2018 09:34' +3 min
  2.      '08/02/2018 09:31' +1 min 
  1.      '08/02/2018 09:30' -- start of data set
```

So the function should:

1. Receive CSV as input
2. Count Rows in CSV file
3. Understand that if it is ODD ROW count, remove last/first row to have even number for rows
4. Then loop count each difference between 2 sets of data and increasing the total
5. Then return the total for the whole set

Which should be in this case i think 94 minutes = 01h:34min:00

Comment: Please calrify *"// I dont know if it is needed but based on my reserach it would be needed // The function should have a fail safe in case if count = odd number of rows, to remove the last one so it will be even."*

Comment: Also please add the PHP code that shows your attempt, so we know where help is needed.

Comment: "I would like to know the approach i should take to calculate the time between each pair of timestamps as a total." define "each pair"? Your example shows each pair is a date and hour?

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with sql

Comment: @RaymondNijland Please read explanation, just think it about it as PunchClock times

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I am no pro-php coder, i understand how to get time elapsed between dates, but i do not know how to Loop through a set (set is total amount of Rows divided by 2) of Datestamps and calculate the elapsed minutes between 1 pair, and then loop through all pairs and get the total time spent.

Comment: @Strawberry well i can always push my CSV into mysql and do it through MYSQL i left it as a options as i know how people like to show multiple ways of getting things done.

Comment: So given the data set above, edit your question to show the desired result.

Comment: Wouldn't the result simply be the difference between the first row and the last one?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Updated

Comment: @RaymondNijland Updated

Comment: @Strawberry Please check my updated question and please check my comment on your answer

Comment: 8.      '08/02/2018 10:00' +1 min
  7.      '08/02/2018 09:49' +10 min

Answer (score 1):

The fail safe request is nonsensical if 1 is compared to 2, and then 2 is compared to 3, so I'll disregard it..

If you wanted to do this in MySQL, you could do something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,dt DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (dt) VALUES
('2018/08/02 11:14:00'),  
('2018/08/02 11:13:00'),  
('2018/08/02 11:13:00'),  
...
('2018/08/02 09:34:00'),  
('2018/08/02 09:31:00'),  
('2018/08/02 09:30:00');  

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(MAX(dt))-TIME_TO_SEC(MIN(dt))) x 
  FROM my_table;
+----------+
| x        |
+----------+
| 01:44:00 |
+----------+
```

Comment: @dExIT No, Strawberry is right. You got a miscalculation from step 7 to 8: `8.      '08/02/2018 10:00' +1 min  7.      '08/02/2018 09:49' +10 min`. The differnce is 11 minutes, not 1 minute. The difference from the first to the last step is equal to the sum of differences between the steps as long as all steps are not negative.